Since Fedora 41, how do you list the groups a particular package belongs to?
Since Fedora 41, the following command does not work anymore:
$ sudo dnf repoquery --groupmember emacs
Unknown argument "--groupmember" for command "repoquery".

Using dnf, how do you list the groups a particular package (for example 'emacs') belongs to?

This option was moved to the group subcommand and renamed to --contains-pkgs. So to get groups emacs belongs to you can use
sudo dnf group info --contains-pkgs emacs

and you'll get
Id                   : editors
Name                 : Editors
Description          : Sometimes called text editors, these are programs that allow you to create and edit text files. This includes Emacs and Vi.
Installed            : no
...
Optional packages    : emacs
                     : emacs-auctex
...

Id                   : python-classroom
Name                 : Python Classroom
Description          : Tools used to teach and learn Python.
Installed            : no
...
Optional packages    : default-editor
                     : emacs


